# AES without mode operation

Tags: aes, cbc, modes-of-operation

i have field in database. ex: field name. this field maybe more than 16 byte. how to encrypt data more than 16 byte without cbc, etc?
any function or another ways to do this?

Comment: Use stream cipher? What is the aim. Just store in the database?

Comment: This is an XY problem; lookup Format Preserving Encryption (or work around the solution by encrypting the database etc.).

Comment: AES without mode of operation operates on exactly 16 bytes, no more, no less. If you post your requirements, we could suggest a suitable mode of operation.

Answer (score 3):

A function that extends your fixed-size cipher to deal with larger inputs is exactly what is called a "Mode of Operation". So any function qualifying would in essence be a "Mode of Operation". There may be solutions if you tell us exactly why a Mode of Operation doesn't work for you

Comment: BaseKing support 192 bits. So if the 192 bits enough this will be a solution.